# How compare two string variables to two string and combine them in AND logic operator in IF conditional statement

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, logical-operators

Yes, I can't believe I am writing this but it seems I can't compare one variable to a string, then second variable to another string and combine those in AND (&&) clause in IF statement for a bash script.

I am trying to do that on Linux Mint 20, GNU bash version 5.0.16. Inside the code you gonna see all the alternative statements I tried and none of those worked.

The script needs to ping my Internet connection twice and if in both cases there is 100% loss of packets I need to start a number of bash commands {not included here} to reconnect the connection. So it is a script for unattended reconnection of internet.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# redirect *pint output to a text file
ping -q -c 8 8.8.8.8 > ~/bash/pingOut.txt

# get transfer loss percentage
lossPerc=$(awk '$5=="received," {print $6}' ~/bash/pingOut.txt)
echo "lossPerc is ${lossPerc}"

# read prev loss percentage
prevLossPerc=$(cat ~/bash/loss-perc.txt)
echo "prevLossPerc is ${prevLossPerc}"

# write latest loss percentage to file
echo "$lossPerc" > ~/bash/loss-perc.txt

#if [[ "$lossPerc" == '+8' ]] && [[ "$prevLostPerc" == '+8' ]] => NO
#if [ "$lossPerc" == '+8' ] && [ "$prevLostPerc" == '+8' ] => NO
#if [ "$lossPerc" = '+8' ] && [ "$prevLostPerc" = '+8' ] => no error but not working as expected ------- line 19 -----
#if [[ $lossPerc = '+8' ]] && [[ $prevLostPerc = '+8' ]] => NO
#if [[ $lossPerc = "+8" ]] && [[ $prevLostPerc = "+8" ]] => NO
#if [ $lossPerc = '+8' ] && [ $prevLostPerc = '+8' ] => NO
#if [ $lossPerc = "+8" ] && [ $prevLostPerc = "+8" ] => NO
#if [[ "$lossPerc" = '+8' && "$prevLostPerc" = '+8' ]] => NO
#if [[ "$lossPerc" == "+8" && "$prevLostPerc" == "+8" ]] => NO
#if [ "$lossPerc" = '+8' && "$prevLostPerc" = '+8' ] NO
then 
    echo "Now I need to do a number of things to reconnect my i-net connection!"
fi
```

So basically I tried all the commented *if statements and all of those but one give errors in the shell. The errors are typically something like `[: =: unexpected operator` or `[[: not found` or `[: missing`. On line 19, there is a statement {marked with extra comment} which doesn't give error but when the condition is true it does nothing i.e. it is not the correct statement either.

Comment: Tried the first one and it works fine here. Are you sure you're running this script using bash?

Comment: Hm, hm, that is funny, I start it like: sh <file_name>. What a bad joke :) Just a moment to run is with *bash.

Comment: Some of your attempts can not work of course, but  the first one, `if [[ $lossPerc == +8 &&  $prevLostPerc´== +8 ]] ` do (no quotes needed here). If the outcome is not what you expected, my guess is that the variable's content is different from what you think. I suggest that you do a `xxd <<<$lossPerc` immediately before testing the variable, to verify its content.

Comment: Yes, my friends, that was the reason for the error {starting the script with *sh instead of *bash}. It is like an old printer manual that read "If your printer doesn't work check if you have connected it to the electric circuit." Exactly my situation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bash rematch:

```
re='\+8'
[[ "$lossPerc" =~ $re ]] && [[ "$prevLostPerc" =~ $re ]]
```

Or even like this:

```
re='\+8.*\+8'
[[ "$lossPerc$prevLostPerc" =~ $re ]]
```

If `case` is also an option:

```
case "$lossPerc$prevLostPerc" in
      *'+8'*'+8'*) echo ok;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks, Ivan! Give me a moment or two to try your code :)))

Comment: This option worked too when I started it like: bash <file_name>
:)))